# How to find the debug SHA 1 key

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am a beginner android developer working on my first project. I unable to find the debug **SHA 1** key through the general procedure

[image]

Comment: your answer is : https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/how-to-get-sha-1-key-in-android-studio-for-firebase/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Go to Android Studio
- Click on Gradle(Right Most of the Screen)
- Click your project name and expand it.
- Then click on Task -> android ->Signing Report
- Android Studio will generate MD1, SHA-1, and SHA-256 for you.

Comment: See the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0rBy.png unable to find that

Comment: Use this link to open gradle task, and then follow above steps.
https://www.programmersought.com/article/82186867935/

Comment: @PRORITESH I had the same problem. Go to Preferences | Experimental and switch off "Do not build Gradle task list during Gradle sync"

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I was also facing this problem with the new Android Studio 4.2 but found the solution eventually

Put this command in the terminal of android studio and hit enter

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

see this image[image]

You will get your debug SHA 1 key
[image]